# php - convert avi to mp4, webm and flv using ffmpeg command

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

My problem is I am trying to convert and upload videos into three formats at upload button. I am stuck at the very first step when i am trying to convert avi to mp4, webm and flv. I have tried various commands to convert in to mp4 and webm but nothing worked. its converting to flv smoothly. i searched a lot on internet but none of the commands worked. i have set execution_time to 0 and set_time_limit(0) as well for unlimited execution time. here are the commands i tried to convert in to mp4 and webm

```
**For mp4:**

exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 output.mp4");
exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4");
exec("ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac \ -movflags +faststart output.mp4");

**For webm** 
passthru("ffmpeg -i input.avi output.webm");
passthru("ffmpeg -i input.avi -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 output.webm");
```

**Note:**
For avi to mp4 files that are less than 1mb are converting successfully but more than 1mb files are showing its converting but its size is 0bytes.

Similarly, i am facing a problem in converting mp4 to flv. Some files are converting and some are not. Some of the large files are converting but some small files are not converting. It was strange. there was no problem of permission or php configuration settings all was fine. I tried renaming a file which was not converting and it got uploaded. I am confused why this happened.

Any help for both the issues is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**
/bin$ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 0.10.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 30 2014 15:49:19 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Missing argument for option 'v'

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you need to debug your exec with files not encoded.
`echo` your `exec` and put it into your shell with the same user than run Apache.

With no log of ffmpeg we can't help you.

For my videos i'm using this for convert avi to mp4 :

```
ffmpeg -i 'filename.ext' -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 19 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -y 'output.mp4'
```

Comment: ok can u please tell me that command how to echo the file info

Comment: `exec("ffmpeg -i 'filename.ext' -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 19 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -y 'output.mp4'",$output)
print_r($output)`

Comment: Check first your ffmpeg build using ffmpeg -v and past it here 
after that test to output log with a converted video bug

Comment: the exec command command shows nothing just Array(). and i have pasted the ffmpeg -v in the question area have a look

Comment: i execute the command in shell WINSCP and using your command it shows this error Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'

Comment: ok ok it's normal because you havn't build ffmpeg with this lib ; try to replace this with your libmp3 and retry

Comment: can u help me with one more thing please. which library should i use for conversion into webm?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -qmin 0 -qmax 50 -crf 5 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm`

Comment: Its showing Unknown encoder 'libvpx' and using other command its showing Unknown encoder 'libvorbis' even these libs and installed

Comment: you need to unistall ffmpeg and build it with this encoder enabled like --with libvpx ... look the docs ffmpeg [link]https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Comment: if you are on a linux dist like ubuntu you can do this `apt-get remove --purge ffmpeg`